# How to prevent Sublime Text 3 from closing after subl in git bash

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, git-bash

Using Git Bash on Windows 10, I added the ***subl*** shortcut to my bash profile to allow me to open and edit files in Sublime Text 3:

```
alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

Previously, I could press ***ctrl-c*** and continue using git bash, while the file being edited (from the ***subl*** cmd) remained open in Sublime Text. Now, something has changed, and continuing to use Git Bash causes the file to close.

For now I am just opening another git bash terminal, but I would like to know what is the setting to prevent the file from closing when continuing with git bash?

The picture below shows the cursor hanging once the subl cmd has been entered (opening the file in sublime) but preventing one from using the console unless ctrl-c is pressed and the file is closed (and I want the file to remain open).

[image]

Comment: Your alias should be to `subl.exe` and not `sublime_text.exe`, but either way as soon as you run the command and it starts, it should immediately return back to the shell unless you use `-w` to tell it to wait for the file to close first.

Answer (score 0):

I use `subl .&` to open my current directory in sublime text.

Using this command will keep the file open and you can continue using gitbash.